# How do I indent my code with the tab-space key?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

For example, how can I type JS some code that looks like this into the Firefox console:

```
if (10 > 5) { 
    alert("Hello world!");
    alert("How are you doing today?");
    alert("I'm doing great, thanks!")
}
```

Without resorting to using the space bar or my operating system's clipboard?

I'd like to be able to use the tab key to indent my code in the Firefox console. Whenever I press tab, Firefox goes through all the elements of the browser and web page without indenting my code.

I'm using the console provided by the `Ctrl+Shift+K` shortcut.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts Says it is tab....

Comment: @epascarello The tab key does not work.

Comment: You could use the Scratchpad (Tools > Web Developer > Scratchpad or Toolbox Options > Scratchpad). It's better designed for multi-line code editing.

Comment: @Alexander Good idea! If you can put that in an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad). It is better-designed for multi-line code editing, and supports using the tab character to indent code.

[image: Scratchpad]

You can find it under the Developer Tools menu. <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Web Developer</kbd> > <kbd>Scratchpad</kbd> on OS X, and <kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Developer</kbd> > <kbd>Scratchpad</kbd> on other platforms.

You can also add it to the Toolbox under <kbd>Toolbox Options</kbd> (the settings gear), and checking the <kbd>Scratchpad</kbd> checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can try Shift + Tab (not sure if that will work on firefox, but it works in Chrome)

This probably wont answer your question either but it might....

> Editor Preferences
>
> Preferences for the CodeMirror source editor, which is included in Firefox and used by several developer tools, including Scratchpad and the Style Editor.
>
> Detect indentation: auto-indent new lines based on the current indentation
>   Autoclose brackets
>   Indent using spaces
>   Tab size
>   Keybindings: choose the default CodeMirror keybindings, or keybindings from one of several popular editors:
>   Vim
>   Emacs
>   Sublime Text

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox

Comment: Neither of those options seem to affect the web console when I tried them. "Editor Preferences" seem to only affect the editor for viewing a website's source code.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have is switch to chrome then O:-)

Answer (score -3):

Just indent. Control + I. Hahahahaha

Comment: Are you sure? Ctrl+L doesn't seem to do anything, and Ctrl+I opens up my bookmark manager...